# Obtaining the quantity and proportion in SPSS 21

Tags: spss

I have the data in a sav file

```
CODE  |  QUANTITY
------|----------
A     |  1
B     |  4
C     |  1
F     |  3
B     |  3
D     |  12
D     |  5
```

I need to obtain the quantity of codes which have a quantity <= 3 and to obtain the proportion in a percentage with respect to the total number and present a result like this

```
<= 3  |  PERCENTAGE
------|----------
4     |  57 %
```

All of this using SPSS syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how you migrate your question here, I dont have reputation here to add screen shoots that's help you allot. Anyhow the procedure of your desire output is given below.

Goto **Transform**->**Count Values within cases** a dialogue box open, write the name of new variable say "**New**" in **Target Variable:**  go to **define values** a new dialogue box is open then check the radio button **Range, LOWEST through value:** put in below box 3 and then press **add** and press **continue** and press **ok**. A new variable is created with the name of "**New**". Now go to **Analyze** -> **Descriptive Statistics**-> **Frequencies**, new dialogue box will be open send "**New**" variable into **Variable(s):** press **Statistics** in new dialogue box check **Percentile(s):** write 100 in box and press **Add** and then **continue** and **ok**. You get the desire results.

Comment: The OP asked for a **syntax** based solution. Working from the GUI like this is often considered [unsound practice](http://www.pythonforspss.org/the-six-greatest-benefits-of-using-spss-syntax/).

Comment: @RubenGeert OP accept the answer, secondly if you have some knowledge about SPSS then syntax is available for any point and click interface command.

Answer (score 2):

I would first convert the quantity value to a 0-1 variable, and then aggregate by code to the mean. This produces a nice second dataset to make a table. Example below.

```
data list free / Code (A1) Quantity (F2.0).
begin data
A 1
B 4
C 1
F 3
B 3
D 12
D 5
end data.

*convert to 0-1.
compute QuantityB3 = (Quantity LE 3).

*Aggregate.
DATASET DECLARE AggQuant.
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE='AggQuant'
  /BREAK=Code
  /QuantityB3 = MEAN(QuantityB3).
```